# Rails connect zip codes to region and search based on results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Looking for a bit of advice as a novice RoR developer.

So I have 8 regions that I'm currently tracking for the continental US. I need to assign to each region a whole slew of zip codes. So for example Southwest - 10001, 10002, 10003, 10004, 10005; Northeast - 20002, 20003, 20004, 20005, 20006, etc.

Would it make the most sense to create a Zipcode Table with an attribute of say zipcode_location to put the zipcodes. Then import the zipcodes with a connection to a region.id(name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty much it.

Each Zipcode will belong to a Region, and have an attribute of region_id to say which one it belongs to.

Each region will have many zipcodes, and you'll be able to do region.zipcodes as well as zipcode.region

```
class Zipcode < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :region
end


class Region < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :zipcodes
end
```